# как хранить несколько значений в одном ключе localStorage

Tags: javascript, localstorage

У меня есть переменная note, которая является основным элементом для заметки, содержащая в себе дочерние элементы.

```
var note = document.createElement("div");
```

Мне надо добавленные заметки хранить и отображать на странице при перезагрузке или выходе из браузера.
Я решил сперва взять содержимое заметки

```
var html = note.outerHTML;
```

Затем сохраняю все в localStorage и вывожу в консоль

```
localStorage.setItem('save_note', html);
    
var storage = localStorage.getItem('save_note');
console.log(storage);
```

Работает нормально первый раз, но добавляя следующие, в хранилище присутствует только последняя добавленная заметка. Еще я не понимаю, как сохраненные заметки показывать при перезагрузки страницы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Храните это в виде массива. Т.е. делайте массив, где будут содержатся заметки. При необходимости добавить - добавляйте в массив и делайте **[JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)** и кладите эту строку в `localStorage`. При извлечении данных из хранилища делайте **[JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)** обратно в массив и работайте с ним.

P.S. Я бы рекомендовал вообще сохранять и извлекать только данные по заметкам, а не сами html. А уже на основе данных из массива - восстанавливать html разметку.